# SFML: Would a Tilemap System With Only One Quad Being Drawn Work?

Tags: c++, optimization, sfml

Thank you for taking the time to read this and to help me with my problem. I've searched this on the internet and I couldn't seem to find any information. I want to make a tilemap, and I thought only using one object and just drawing it across the screen would be more optimized than handling all objects individually for each tile. I couldn't find any information on this idea and if it is a good idea or not.

How it works is I have a function that calls to make the tilemap with the textures at a specified size. Then it uses one quad object in 2 nested for loops that specify the vertices and textures and then draws. It repeats this until the whole tilemap is drawn the displays.

Here is the bulk of the tilemap making function - tileMap is the  quad.

```
    while(iY < sizeX)
{
    while(iX < sizeY)
    {
        // Posistion the verticies
        tileMap[0].position = sf::Vector2f(SizeX + offsetX, SizeY + offsetX);
        tileMap[1].position = sf::Vector2f((SizeX + size) + offsetX, SizeY + offsetX);
        tileMap[2].position = sf::Vector2f((SizeX + size) + offsetX, (SizeY + size) + offsetY);
        tileMap[3].position = sf::Vector2f(SizeX + offsetX, (SizeY + size) + offsetY);
        // Texture the verticies
        tileMap[0].texCoords = sf::Vector2f(tex[t][0],tex[t][1]);
        tileMap[1].texCoords = sf::Vector2f(tex[t][2],tex[t][3]);
        tileMap[2].texCoords = sf::Vector2f(tex[t][4],tex[t][5]);
        tileMap[3].texCoords = sf::Vector2f(tex[t][6],tex[t][7]);
        iX += 1;
        SizeX += size;
        // Draw current tile
        window.draw(tileMap, &tilemapSheet);
    }
    iX = 0;
    SizeX = 0;
    SizeY += size;
    iY += 1;
}
```

Ask me for any questions about the code.

Thanks again for helping me.

Comment: Quaternions describe rotations, what do rotations have to do with drawing axis-aligned rectangles on the screen?

Comment: I am so sorry, I meant quad. Sorry about that. I edited the post.

Comment: When you say "one object", are you referring to one quad? Or one texture? Cause what you're describing sounds like one texture + multiple quads, but you don't describe the alternative solution you're considering.

Comment: The normal way to render a tilemap is by using multiple objects, but I thought of the idea of only using one object and then moving and drawing it, and only displaying it after every tile is drawn. The quad has its texture defined in the for loop. I'll post the code on my post.

Comment: oh I understand what you mean now, the quad has a texture, they aren't seperate.

Comment: @Blindy its been 4 hours, just wondering if you missed what I said.

Comment: No, I figured that if I have to ask a THIRD time what in the world you mean I might as well just close your question. Specifically, it's still not clear what are the two alternatives you're trying to choose between, and I find phrases like "The normal way to ... is ..." to provide no value when described by someone who confuses quaternions with quads, no offense. I would suggest perhaps drawing an image in Paint with what exactly you're wondering about.

Comment: If it helps, the usual way tile maps are drawn is a bunch of triangles in a VAO that describe the visible board and texture indices (as you have), and a texture atlas bound to your single texture unit. You draw any sprites in your atlas and store its texcoords either at build time or at runtime.

Comment: I'm sorry if I caused confusion. The method I used for my tilemap was to have one quad with a texture, (that can change, but that's not important), that goes into a position, gets drawn, then goes a new position, gets drawn, and repeats it within a loop, show on the for loops while Y < than something, X < something. There is only one object, but it gets drawn everytime it moves within the for loop. It only displays the results after the for loops are done.

Comment: The alternative solution is just to use a grid of objects that have the textures of the tilemap I want. This is the normal method and is shown here. https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/graphics-vertex-array.php (scroll down until you see "example: tilemap"

Comment: hope that clears things up

Comment: So the alternative is individual draw calls for every single tile map cell? In a world where you're actively punished by your graphics driver for every draw call you make, and where Vulkan applications must render the entire scene in under 3 draw calls or run at single digit fps, the answer should be obvious: one draw call for the entire sprite scene. That includes the tile map and all sprites you have in your world, and all the text (unless you're using SDF text, in which case a second draw call is acceptable).

Comment: Also you shouldn't be using quads, no graphics driver has support for it and has to transform your call to individual triangles.

Comment: I didn't know draw caIls were so ineffiecient. can only use quads for my tilemap. Thanks for your help.